# Creating a generic function in Java for builders of different implementations of interface

Tags: java, builder, lombok

```
public interface A extends C {
    String getCh();
    String getId();
    String getReview();
}

public interface B extends C {
    String getCh();
    String getId();
    String getReview();
}

@Data
@Builder
public class AImpl implements A{
    private String ch;
    private String id;
    private String review;
}

@Data
@Builder
public class BImpl implements B{
    private String ch;
    private String id;
    private String review;
}

so now to use the builders of these I do:

return AImpl.builder()
        .ch("ch")
        .id("id")
        .review("somerview");

For B I do:
return BImpl.builder()
        .ch("ch1")
        .id("id1")
        .review("some new review");
```

Is there a way where I can make this builder part into a function? I dont like the idea of repeating the same code again. Like where I can pass id channel and review in a function and I can the object?

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I have never really dealt with builders so there might be a really much better option :D

This approach writes builders for each interface individually.
This does require that the interfaces provide a setter method.
Using generics, the methods of the RootBuilder and BaseABuilder return an instance of the ImplABuilder so that the chain can continue properly.

This is a very simple implementation of the Thistype generic which in other languages exists by default. This implementation also relies on casting to the actual Thistype but if you set the generics properly, that shouldnt be an issue.

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ImplA implA = ImplA
            .builder()
            .id("id")
            .description("description")
            .valueA("a")
            .build();
    }
}

public interface Root
{
    String getId();
    void setId(String id);
    String getDescription();
    void setDescription(String description);
}

public class RootBuilder<Thistype extends RootBuilder<Thistype, Instance>, Instance extends Root>
{
    protected final Instance object;

    RootBuilder(Instance object)
    {
        this.object = object;
    }

    public Thistype id(String value)
    {
        object.setId(value);
        return (Thistype)this;
    }

    public Thistype description(String value)
    {
        object.setDescription(value);
        return (Thistype)this;
    }

    public Instance build()
    {
        return object;
    }
}

public interface BaseA extends Root
{
    String getValueA();
    void setValueA(String valueA);
}

public class BaseABuilder<Thistype extends BaseABuilder<Thistype, Instance>, Instance extends BaseA> extends RootBuilder<Thistype, Instance>
{
    protected Instance object;

    BaseABuilder(Instance object)
    {
        super(object);
    }

    public Thistype valueA(String value)
    {
        object.setValueA(value);
        return (Thistype)this;
    }
}

public interface BaseB extends Root
{
    String getValueB();
    void setValueB(String valueB);
}

public interface BaseC extends Root
{
    String getValueC();
    void setValueC(String valueC);
}

public final class ImplA implements BaseA
{
    private String id;
    private String description;
    private String valueA;

    private ImplA() { }

    public static ImplABuilder builder()
    {
        return new ImplABuilder(new ImplA());
    }

    private static class ImplABuilder extends BaseABuilder<ImplABuilder, ImplA> // assuming ImplA is final
    {
        ImplABuilder(ImplA object)
        {
            super(object);
        }

        // additional methods for ImplA class
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Though this seems to be a lot more complex than writing the code twice. I wont be able to use @Builder provided by Lombok too